# Who profits when new Stack websites are created?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, business-model

I think that StackOverflow does a number of things very well and it's cool to see the new web sites that are appearing that use the Stack protocol.  I visited "Area 51" the other day and saw some interesting proposals.

I understand that StackOverflow is monetized by the career section and the advertisements.

My question is, Who profits from the creation of new Stack sites?  Do the creators of the new sites find sponsors on their own and try to make a profit?  How does it work?

Comment: I don't know, but we all *gain* from it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, I think the only source of revenue is from advertising.

When the VC funding was [announced on the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/announcing-our-series-a/) by Joel, he said

> One of [the investors] suggested that we don’t hard code our revenue model too early. If the platform creates value for a lot of people, he told us, we’ll have plenty of opportunities to make money that actually make the site better.

Meaning they are creating the value first, and waiting to see what kinds of revenue models grow out of that (which is generally a better strategy than doing the reverse).

Comment: Currently, the only source of revenue is advertising you say.  My question is about who is making (or losing) money from the new Stack web sites.

Comment: @Rising Star: Currently only Stack Overflow Inc. and their investor group. However, given that the revenue model is up in the air, it's *possible* members of the sites could be included in that. Really what I'm saying is that there is no answer to your question yet.

Answer (score 2):

The authors of Area 51 proposals don't have any special "ownership" of the site. There has been some talk about appointing them as temporary moderators (until there is an election) but nothing like that has been implemented, yet. Hopefully, we will find other ways to "reward" exceptional contribution to new sites as we continue to grow.

All Stack Exchange sites will be owned and administered under the same general model as Stack Overflow. All content will be licensed under [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) (always free for reuse with attribution), the site design copyright of Stack Overflow Inc, and the mission is basically the same for all sites.

Since each site is tightly focused on a specific subject, we will continue to look for ways to provide value-added services that benefit both parties. That means providing services such as career listings, displaying relevant and responsible advertising, and keeping an eye out for services that in some way "give back" to each individual community.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but you haven't answered my original question.  Who earns (or loses) money from the new Stack web sites that are going up?

Comment: @Rising Star: Sorry. Direct answer: Stack Overflow Inc.